# Django Auth Group refuses to change in UpdateViews

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm having a problem to update the User Group field after the User creation.
The focus here is do this kind of thing outside the Admin page, in common UpdateView that will have limited access for certain groups.
What bugged me is that the Group selection and saving of the EditForm and EditView is identical to the CreationForm/CreationView, and those work flawlessly.
It just refuses to change, it doesn't throw any error, just like there were no relations between this tables (auth_group and users_customuser_groups) at all.

---

**views.py**

```
class UserEdit(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = EditUserForm
    template_name = 'registration/edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = EditUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)

            user.save()

            group = Group.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['group'])

            group.user_set.add(user)
            group.save()
            form.save()

        return redirect('dashboard')
```

---

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Group
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from .managers import CustomUserManager
from institutes.models import Institute


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, verbose_name='institute', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

---

**forms.py**

```
class EditUserForm(UserChangeForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    is_staff = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    is_active = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                                   required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    institute = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Institute.objects.all(),
                                       required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'password', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'group', 'institute')
```

Some tables to help:

```
DB=# SELECT * FROM auth_group;
 id |   name    
----+-----------
  1 | Professor
  2 | Validador
(2 rows)

DB=# SELECT * FROM users_customuser_groups;
 id | customuser_id | group_id 
----+---------------+----------
  3 |             6 |        1  --> **THIS ONE SHOULD BE ID=2**
  4 |             7 |        1
  5 |             8 |        2
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using generic UpdateView you can just override `form_valid` method.

```
class UserEdit(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = EditUserForm
    template_name = 'registration/edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')

    def form_valid(self, form):
         user = form.save()
         group = Group.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['group'])
         group.user_set.add(user)
         return super().form_valid(form)
```